# How to display random images without repetition using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to display 2 random images on a page with no repetition. I am able to display random images but with repetition using the following code.

```
function ranImage() {

   picture = new Array(" array of pictures");
   whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*picture.length);
   document.write('<LMG SRC="' +picture[whichImage]+ '">');

}
```

Need Help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If that's all you're doing, you can pop the already displayed images out of your array.

Comment: ...by just adding the line `picture.splice(whichImage, 1)` at the end of your function.

Comment: splice is exactly the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save which ones you did show already. This one will work until exhausted all the images:

```
var alreadyShown = new Array();

function ranImage() {

picture = new Array(" array of pictures");

for (picture.length != alreadyShown; whichImage = Math.floor(Math.random()*picture.length); arr.indexOf(whichImage) == -1){
   alreadyShown[alreadyShown.length+1] = whichImage;
}

document.write('<LMG SRC="' +picture[whichImage]+ '">');

}
```